# Can someone explain this K8s ingress file

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, ingress-controller

I have encountered this ingress file and struggling to understand http (& , *) meaning in this ingress file- Can some one please explain * and & meaning here?

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
  name: my-example
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http: &exampleBackendService
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-example
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
  - host: example-dev.com
    http: *exampleBackendService
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all *yaml* grammer, nothing with `k8s`. see [Anchors and Aliases](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#3222-anchors-and-aliases), or a [simpler tutorial](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/yaml-anchors/).
The purpose is reuse, shorter and maintainability.

You can use python(among many choices) to expand:

```py
import yaml


class ExplicitDumper(yaml.SafeDumper):
    def ignore_aliases(self, data):
        return True


d = yaml.safe_load('''your very long yaml string''')
print(yaml.dump(d, Dumper=ExplicitDumper))
```

output

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
  name: my-example
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-example
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
  - host: example-dev.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-example
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```